# js: Uncaught ReferenceError: (my function) is not defined

Tags: python, pyqt, folium

```
def createFoliumMap(self):
coordinate = (36.1908784, 127.1577341)
m = folium.Map(
title='map',
zoom_start=8,
location=coordinate,
width='100%',
height='100%'
)

    js_definition = """
    <script>
        function removeOtherMarkers(map, clickedMarker) {
            var allMarkers = map._layers;
            var clickedLat = clickedMarker._latlng.lat;
            var clickedLng = clickedMarker._latlng.lng;

            for (var markerId in allMarkers) {
                var marker = allMarkers[markerId];
                if (marker instanceof L.Marker) {
                    var markerLat = marker._latlng.lat;
                    var markerLng = marker._latlng.lng;

                    if (markerLat !== clickedLat || markerLng !== clickedLng) {
                        map.removeLayer(marker);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    """
    m.get_root().html.add_child(folium.Element(js_definition))
        
    for location, popup in zip(self.locations, self.popups):
        city_name, info = popup.split(":\n")
        
        html = f"""
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <b>{city_name}:</b><br>
            <span>{info}</span><br>
            <button style="margin-right: 10px; padding: 5px 15px; cursor: pointer;" onclick='removeOtherMarkers(m, this)'>Detail</button>
            <button style="margin-top: 10px; padding: 5px 15px; cursor: pointer;" onclick='Select.js'>Select</button>
        </div>
        """

        iframe = folium.IFrame(html=html, width=250, height=100)
        iframe.sandbox = "allow-scripts"
        popup = folium.Popup(iframe, max_width=300)
```

I want to implement a feature that excludes all markers except the one clicked with the 'Detail' button among the approximately 8 folium markers. I attempted to implement this by separating the JavaScript file, but failed. So, I directly added it to the HTML code. However, I keep getting an error like:

```
js: Uncaught ReferenceError: removeOtherMarkers is not defined.
```

I'm not sure if the problem is with the code, folium, or the PyQt environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `<script>` tags from `js_definition` and use `m.get_root().script` instead of `m.get_root().html`.

```python
def createFoliumMap(self):

    coordinate = (36.1908784, 127.1577341)
    m = folium.Map(title='map',
                   zoom_start=8,
                   location=coordinate,
                   width='100%',
                   height='100%')
    
    # remove '<script>' tags
    js_definition = """
        function removeOtherMarkers(map, clickedMarker) {
            var allMarkers = map._layers;
            var clickedLat = clickedMarker._latlng.lat;
            var clickedLng = clickedMarker._latlng.lng;
        
            for (var markerId in allMarkers) {
                var marker = allMarkers[markerId];
                if (marker instanceof L.Marker) {
                    var markerLat = marker._latlng.lat;
                    var markerLng = marker._latlng.lng;
        
                    if (markerLat !== clickedLat || markerLng !== clickedLng) {
                        map.removeLayer(marker);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    """
    
    # use '.script' instead of '.html'
    m.get_root().script.add_child(folium.Element(js_definition))

    # ... other code
```

Comment: I made the modifications, but it's still not working. When I checked in the developer tools, it says "Uncaught Error: Model is disposed!"